# Integral containing exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to prove below (Reference: Green's function with application, page 159):
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(x-y)\tau}}{\tau^4-a^4}d\tau=\frac{1}{4a^3}(ie^{ia|x-y|}-e^{-a|x-y|})$$

When trying to calculate the integral, I used Wolfram, and I get the following:
$$\int\frac{e^{(x-y)i\tau}}{\tau^4-a^4}d\tau=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{{\omega:a^4-\omega^4=0}}\frac{e^{i(x-y)\omega}Ei(iA(\tau-\omega))}{\omega^3}+const$$
I am not sure how to deal with Ei function for an imaginary number with specified integral boundary.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit them right away!

Comment: You have given W-A and indefinite integral, where the first integral is an improper integral.  Applying the limits of integration to the expression on the bottom should give you the one on the top.

Comment: Thanks, Doug, Applying limit of integral, I would get the Ei of negative infinite imaginary number, how I can calculate that?

Comment: Dear Doug M and Sangchul Lee, I tried to apply the same solution you described to another problem in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954151/double-integral-with-complex-numbers I appreciate if you can take a look and let you know if you have any comments/suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate this integral use complex analysis.  We make a contour with the real line and a semi-circle through the upper-half of the complex plane.

As the radius of the semi-circle goes to infinity, the integral along this piece of the contour goes to $0.$

Now we just need to examine the residuals.

$\tau^4 - a^4 = (\tau - a)(\tau - ia)(\tau + a)(\tau + ia)$

Two of these poles will be inside the contour, and 2 will be outside the contour.  In order to know which two to pick, lets assume that a has positive real and imaginary parts.

$\oint_\gamma \frac {e^{i|x-y|\tau}}{\tau^4 - a^4} \ d\tau$

$2\pi i \left[\lim_\limits{\tau \to a} \frac {e^{|x-y|\tau}}{\tau^4 - a^4}(\tau - a) + \lim_\limits{\tau \to ia} \frac {e^{|x-y|\tau}}{\tau^4 - a^4}(\tau - ia)\right]$

$2\pi i \left[\frac {e^{i|x-y|a}}{4a^3} + \frac{e^{i|x-y|(ia)}}{4(ia)^3}\right]$

$2\pi i \left[\frac {e^{i|x-y|a}+ie^{-|x-y|a}}{4a^3}\right]$

$2\pi \left[\frac {ie^{i|x-y|a} - e^{-|x-y|a}}{4a^3}\right]$

Comment: Thanks Doug! I really appreciate your solution :)

Comment: Poles $\pm a$ lie on the real line. How do you deal with them? Especially, do you only include $a$ instead of both $\pm a$, and why does the prefactor of the residue at $\tau=a$ become $2\pi$?

Comment: if a is real (or pure imaginary for that matter) this integral will not converge..

Comment: Ah, that perfectly makes sense. I somehow assumed that OP was considering the integral for real $a$ and in Cauchy principal sense.

Answer (score 2):

**@Doug M** already posted an answer assuming that $a$ is neither real nor pure imaginary. In this answer, I will tackle the opposite case, i.e., the case with $a > 0$.

If $a > 0$, then the integrand suffers from poles $\pm a$ along the real line, and so, the integral does not converge in ordinary sense. For this reason, we will interpret the integral in *Cauchy principal value sense*. Then by noting that the imaginary part of the integrand is an odd function, we get

$$ I
:= \frac{1}{2\pi} \operatorname{PV}\! \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i(x-y)\tau}}{\tau^4-a^4} \, \mathrm{d}\tau
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \operatorname{PV}\! \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos((x-y)\tau)}{\tau^4-a^4} \, \mathrm{d}\tau. $$

In particular, the integral depends only on $k := \left| x - y \right|$.

Now by applying the residue theorem applied to the contour integral along the dented semicircular arc

[image: Contour]

and then letting the outer radius to $\infty$ and the inner radii to $0^+$, we get

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \operatorname{PV}\! \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik\tau}}{\tau^4-a^4} \, \mathrm{d}\tau \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \biggl( i\pi \, \mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=a} \, \frac{e^{ikz}}{z^4-a^4} + i\pi \, \mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=-a} \, \frac{e^{ikz}}{z^4-a^4} + 2i\pi \, \mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=ia} \, \frac{e^{ikz}}{z^4-a^4} \biggr) \\
&= \frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{ika}}{4a^3} + \frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{-ika}}{4(-a)^3} + i \frac{e^{-ak}}{4(ia)^3} \\
&= - \frac{1}{4a^3}\bigl( \sin(ak) + e^{-ak} \bigr) \\
&= - \frac{1}{4a^3}\bigl( \sin(a\left|x-y\right|) + e^{-a\left|x-y\right|} \bigr).
\end{align*}

Notice that this coincides with the real part of the proposed answer by OP.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, In the beginning of the question in the book, it mentions a>0. I really appreciate your help :)