# Double Integral with Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I have trouble calculating below integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i(\omega y+\beta x)}}{a+b\beta^2+c\omega^2+ik\beta}d\beta d\omega$$
where a, b, c, k are real constants and positive. $x$ and $y$ are also constant but not necessarily positive but they are real. I tried to follow Cauchy principal value based on my previous question in [Integral containing exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946216/integral-containing-exponential) but I couldn't solve it.
Please let me know if you need further information. Thanks and Happy Holiday.

**Update 1:** With some guidance, I followed below solution:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\beta x}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i\omega y}}{a+b\beta^2+c\omega^2+ik\beta} d\omega d\beta$$
I focused at the internal integral (with respect to $\omega$). The denumonetor would have two roots:
$$c\omega^2+(a+b\beta^2)+ik\beta$$
I used the post in here: [How do I get the square root of a complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number)
So the roots would be:
$$\omega_r=\mp (\sqrt\frac{(a+b\beta^2)+\sqrt{(a+b\beta^2)^2+(k\beta)^2}}{2a}+i\sqrt\frac{-(a+b\beta^2)+\sqrt{(a+b\beta^2)^2+(k\beta)^2}}{2a})$$
Then I tried to follow complex integral considering positive roots is inside contour (please correct me if it is wrong). Doing so, I ended up with the internal integral to be equal to $\frac{\pi i}{\omega_r}e^{iy\omega_r}$. Considering this solution, the overall integral would become:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt{A+B\beta^2+\sqrt{C\beta^4+D\beta^2+E}}+i\sqrt{-A-B\beta^2+\sqrt{C\beta^4+D\beta^2+E}}}e^{i(\beta x+(\sqrt{A+B\beta^2+\sqrt{C\beta^4+D\beta^2+E}}+i\sqrt{-A-B\beta^2+\sqrt{C\beta^4+D\beta^2+E}})y)}d\beta$$
At this stage, I don't think the denumenator has any root (??). I appreciate if you can take a look and confirm if I am in the right direction and how I can calculate the final integral. Thanks

**Update 2**: This time, I started from $\beta$ variable first. Doing so, I found the roots of the denominator as:
$$\beta_r=\frac{-ik\mp\sqrt{-k^2-4ab-4bc\omega^2}}{-2b}$$
Note that in this equation, the parameters are positive so I write it as:
$$\beta_r=\frac{-ik\mp i\sqrt{k^2+4ab+4bc\omega^2}}{-2b}$$
So based on this I found the integral becomes:
$$-2\pi b\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i\omega y-ikx+ ix\sqrt{k^2+4ab+4bc\omega^2}}}{\sqrt{k^2+4ab+4bc\omega^2}}d\omega$$
Then, The roots for the denominator would be:
$$\omega_r= \mp i \sqrt(\frac{b}{c})$$. Now, I need to find residue at these roots?

Comment: Integrate $\omega$ first, you should get something that looks like $$f(a,b,c,k,\beta)\exp(-|g(a,b,c,k,\beta)\cdot y|+i\beta x)$$

Comment: I don't think this converges.

Comment: Ninad, I tried but not sure how to deal with roots of denominator which would be $\omega^2+Ai+B$.

Comment: Thanks, David, I appreciate if you can explain more.

Comment: Dear All, I updated the solution and more or less reach to what Ninad mentioned. I appreciate if you can provide me with some feedback. Thanks.